# Order of JSR-303 and Validatable validation in play

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, bean-validation

In a Play (now 2.6) project, both annotation based validation (for example, `@Constraints.Required`) as well as validation via the `Validatable` (plus `@Validate`) are used. This worked fine until now, but as of play 2.6 both are now executed simultaneously per default.

This leads to the unfortunate effect, that the `validate` method (from `Validatable`) can now no longer be sure that all the other validations have already finished successfully, so we must add various null-checks, etc. in `validate` on fields that are already marked not-null per annotation.

Is there a way in Play 2.6 to get the behavior, that `validate()` is only called after all annotation based validation rules have finished successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#form-changes:

> Be aware: The “old” validate method was invoked only after all other constraints were successful before. By default class-level constraints however are called simultaneously with any other constraint annotations - no matter if they passed or failed. To (also) define an order between the constraints you can now use constraint groups.

This is how that looks:

```
import javax.validation.GroupSequence;
import javax.validation.groups.Default;

@GroupSequence({ Default.class, SignUpCheck.class, LoginCheck.class })
public interface OrderedChecks { }
```

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaForms#advanced-validation for details.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that there was a simpler solution than groups, but that's very likely the way we'll also be taking.